# Open d3 visual to specific location (icicle)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Using the D3 [icicle](https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoomable-icicle) visual on Observable.

How can I navigate to a specific rect without having to click through. So if a user opens the visual, it would programmatically naivgate to/open the visual deeper in the hierarchy.

I've tried working with the focus code in the clicked callback, but cannot see how to set this properly.

```
focus = focus === p ? p = p.parent : p;
root.each(d => d.target = {
    x0: (d.x0 - p.x0) / (p.x1 - p.x0) * height,
    x1: (d.x1 - p.x0) / (p.x1 - p.x0) * height,
    y0: d.y0 - p.y0,
    y1: d.y1 - p.y0
});
```